# Increase 1 to variable ,when we create an object

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, static

Hey I'm creating a employed program I tried to make the constructor share value but it wont create a class called (employed ) that inlcude instance variables : 
name string ; 
num int ; 
count int his instanse is 120 ; 
create proparaty 
that set and get name 
and proparaty 
to  get count
*
for every creating object we increase 1 to count

```
public class employed //creating class
    { // creating instanse variable 
        private string name;
        private  int number;
        private static int count; //declare it as a static so we can use it in a static method
        public string proparaty
        {
            set
            { name = value; }
            get { return name; } 
        }
        public int propartyForCount
        {

            get
            {
                return count;
            }
        }
       static employed() { // we make it static so we can share the value 
           count = 120;
           count++;

        }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        employed c1 = new employed();
        employed c2 = new employed();
        employed c3 = new employed(); 
        Console.Write("the count number is {0} ", c1.propartyForCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Static Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) is executed only once for type (before first usage of type). From MSDN:

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class
>   before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced.

So, you will have `count` increased only once.

If you want to increase this variable each time when new employee is instantiated, then you should do it in instance constructor:

```
private static int count = 120;

public employed() 
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: You can add that OP may increase that static counter from an instance constructor (it's a suggestion)

Comment: Uhm, you thought the same hahaha